# What polyatomic substances have the lowest known freezing points at standard pressure?

Tags: phase, temperature, liquids

At standard pressure, helium never freezes, so that's clearly *the* coldest liquid—but it's also a monatomic substance.

Diatomic hydrogen freezes at 13 K.

Neon freezes at 24 K.

And then the next coldest liquid I can find documented is $\ce{OF2},$ which is liquid between 49 K and 128 K (which I only know because Robert Forward references it in the science fiction novel *Camelot 30K*).

Are there any other known compounds which have freezing/melting points between 0 K and 50 K?

Comment: What non-monoatomic gases do you know? Hint: you are looking for nonpolar, small, and light molecules. I can think of just *four* in all that make sense to take into account.

Comment: I don't like the wording of the question. It sounds like HNQ bait. Also liquids can be supercooled well below melting point.

Comment: @Karl Well, O2, N2, CO2, CH4, CF4, and CCl4 all freeze at higher temperatures. OCl2 freezes at a higher temperature and is not non-polar. The analogous nitrogen compounds are all polar, and freeze at higher temperatures. What are *you* thinking of?

Comment: @Mithoron How would you improve it?

Comment: [Lowest freezing point room temperature liquid?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/27027/lowest-freezing-point-room-temperature-liquid)

Comment: @andselisk That's a very different question, for which I would expect little or no overlap in answers. Neither hydrogen, nor neon, nor OF2 are liquid at room temperature, for example.

Comment: The title and the text ask two very different questions. One is about a substance in the known set of substances, and the other is absolute.

Comment: @Zhe The title was edited without my consent in a way that contradicts the body. Having not received any suggestions on how to improve it, I guess I'll take a while guess and edit it again...